# Org export LaTeX: Multiple dashes in ~code~/=verbatim= turn into wrong number of dashes

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

[image]

As shown in the image, `~--~` becomes `\texttt{-{}-}` which turn into 2 dashes in the `PDF`.

Reason behind seems to be: LaTeX thinks `--` as a single character (TeX-ligature for en.dash). And, `{}` in `-{}-`  separates the two. ([take a look here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9814/292504)). So, it seems that org wants to export  multiple dashes into same amount dashes (no ligature). Plus, Text in the `~code~` and `=verbatim=` shouldn't get TeX-ligatures:

> Text in the code and verbatim string is not processed for Org specific syntax; it is exported verbatim.

By these logic, shouldn't `~----~` become `\texttt{-{}-{}-{}-{}-}` (actual 4 dashes) instead of `\texttt{-{}--{}-}` (dash + en.dash + dash)?

```org
                |                                        |                                            
 Original Org   |   Exported  tex file  section          |   Shouldn't be like this?                                    
                |                                        |                                          
* code          |      \section{code}                    |     \section{code}
 1. ~-~         |      \label{sec:org532ffa5}            |     \label{sec:org532ffa5}
 2. ~--~        |      \begin{enumerate}                 |     \begin{enumerate}
 3. ~---~       |      \item \texttt{-}                  |     \item \texttt{-}
 4. ~----~      |      \item \texttt{-{}-}               |     \item \texttt{-{}-}
 5. ~-----~     |      \item \texttt{-{}--}              |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-}
 6. ~a------b~  |      \item \texttt{-{}--{}-}           |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-{}-}
                |      \item \texttt{-{}--{}--}          |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-{}-{}-}
* verbatim      |      \item \texttt{a-{}--{}--{}-b}     |     \item \texttt{a-{}-{}-{}-{}-{}-b}
 1. =-=         |      \end{enumerate}                   |     \end{enumerate}
 2. =--=        |                                        |
 3. =---=       |      \section{verbatim}                |     \section{verbatim}
 4. =----=      |      \label{sec:org4a05ec4}            |     \label{sec:org4a05ec4}
 5. =-----=     |      \begin{enumerate}                 |     \begin{enumerate}
 6. =a------b=  |      \item \texttt{-}                  |     \item \texttt{-}
                |      \item \texttt{-{}-}               |     \item \texttt{-{}-}
                |      \item \texttt{-{}--}              |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-}
                |      \item \texttt{-{}--{}-}           |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-{}-}
                |      \item \texttt{-{}--{}--}          |     \item \texttt{-{}-{}-{}-{}-}
                |      \item \texttt{a-{}--{}--{}-b}     |     \item \texttt{a-{}-{}-{}-{}-{}-b}
                |      \end{enumerate}                   |     \end{enumerate}
```

I'm guessing what's going on behind the curtains: it replaces `--` with `-{}-`. So 4 dashes (`----`) has 2 `--` so each couple get replaced with `-{}-` finally forming `-{}--{}-`.

---

- Is my reasoning right?
- Is this legit bug?
- Or, Is there any reason behind it works the way this is?

Comment: It's very much a corner case and the output is probably an implementation accident. You probably should submit a bug report: `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: Reported it, thanks. I didn't knew org bug report was separate than `report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Both  will work I think: Org devs are watching the Emacs bug reports coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

The bug was reported [here](https://list.orgmode.org/2ed6592c-4d4f-eee4-0d27-f3d4184e7a45@gmail.com/T/#md58dd5b3c7f1cc7e914ca507fffb75325f15810d).

And now, [maintainer](https://list.orgmode.org/2ed6592c-4d4f-eee4-0d27-f3d4184e7a45@gmail.com/T/#md58dd5b3c7f1cc7e914ca507fffb75325f15810d) fixed the bug [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=5ac1ebaa1)